# Airflow jobs on MWAA fail with no Log messages

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, mwaa

I have been using Airflow on AWS(MWAA) for a couple of months now and I noticed that occasionally some Airflow tasks fail with no discernable reason and with no log messages in Cloudwatch. I often have to clear and retry the tasks multiple times for the task to eventually succeed.

Does anyone know the reason why this would be happening? I'm thinking with the autoscaling feature of MWAA this should not be an issue of resources. Anyone with any experience dealing with something like this or with any idea would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it updating apache-airflow-providers-celery to 3.3.4. I am using MWAA mw1.small with Airflow version 2.5.1. The default apache-airflow-providers-celery is 3.1.0.
Update your requirements file to apache-airflow-providers-celery==3.3.4. I am using a versioned bucket so I had to update my file and then point to latest version on MWAA configurations. If you updated it correctly you can check it on UI (Admin -> Providers).
Link to update requirements file on MWAA:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/working-dags-dependencies.html#working-dags-dependencies-how